# pass array from c++/cli to C# in a 'typesafe' way

Tags: c#, c++, .net, arrays, command-line-interface

which is the easiest way to return a list/vector/array of objects from c++/cli to c# in a typesafe way?

```
//C++/CLI project 1
public ref class MyClass
{
}

public ref class Factory
{
    array<MyClass^> getObjects() {...}
}

//C# project 2
Factory f = new Factory();
System.Array a = f.getObjects(); // not typesafe! I'd like to get an array/list/vector of MyClass elements
```

I tried returning a

```
List<MyClass^>
```

from C++ and read an

```
IList<MyClass^>
```

from C#, it didn't compile...

thanks,
Chris

Comment: Did you mean `IList<MyClass>` on the C# side?

Comment: What exactly is the problem on C# side? Does `MyClass[] a = c.getObjects()` not work?

Comment: MyClass[] objects = f.getObjects(); //works, thanks a lot (I'm a newbie to C#)

Comment: That should be `array<MyClass^>^` (note the additional `^`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array in C++/CLI is "managed pointer" (called reference), therefore it is written as `array<Type>^`. You can initialize it via `gcnew array<Type, dimension>(count)` which equals to C# `new Type[count]`, when dimension is 1.

So in your case, it could look like this:

```
array<MyClass^>^ getObjects() { 
    return gcnew array<MyClass^,1>(number) ; 
}
```